# Build expression that executes another expression

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

I would like to build an expression that uses another expression, and that will give me a nice `ToString()` output.

Expressed with normal lambdas, I'd like to do this:

```
Func<string> extractFunc = () => "Marsh";
Func<bool> compareFunc = () => extractFunc() == "Mallow";
```

Same thing with expressions:

```
Expression<Func<string>> extractExp = () => "Marsh";
Expression<Func<bool>> compareExp = () => extractExp.Compile()() == "Mallow";
```

Executing `compareExp.ToString()` gives me the following output:

```
() => (Invoke(value(MyClass+<>c__DisplayClassb).extractExp.Compile()) == "Mallow")
```

What I would like is something similar to this:

```
() => "March" == "Mallow"
```

What should I write instead of `extractExp.Compile()()`?

(I might have to use some kind of `ExpressionVisitor` to get the beautiful output. Bonus if the answer includes that, but more important is how to merge the two `Expression`s.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for here is a `Compose` method, that can take an expression and map it into a method that takes the same input, but performs an operation on the result of the first function:

```
public static Expression<Func<TResult>>
    Compose<TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TResult>>(
        second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], first.Body));
}
```

This method uses the following method to replace all instances of one expression with another:

```
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
```

Now you can write:

```
Expression<Func<string>> extractExp = () => "Marsh";
Expression<Func<bool>> compareExp = extractExp.Compose(s => s == "Mallow");
```